# How to increase Java heap size for Carrot2?

Tags: carrot2

How can I increase Java heap size for Carrot2 Document Clustering Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via command line:

carrot2-workbench -vmargs -Xmx256m

Tip: You can use the above pattern to specify any other JVM options if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
carrot2-workbench -vmargs -Xmx256m
```

Another tip:

You can also add `JVM` path and options to the `eclipse.ini` file located in in `Carrot2 Document Clustering Workbench` installation directory. Please see `Eclipse Wiki` for a list of all available options.